# INNER JOIN with multiple tabels

Tags: php, pdo, inner-join

I Have PHP Script That SELECT FROM 7 Tabels and client_id is the Common Column
And Return Single Tebel With all the clients by as there client_id row after row, now The problem is the if there is in one Tabel tow rows with 2 duplicate id  That's print duplicate rows like 100 times

maybe i don't do INNER JOIN right or something if someone has an idea how to prevent this

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM client_form cf
 INNER JOIN client_form_2 cf2 ON cf.client_id = cf2.client_id
 INNER JOIN client_form_3 cf3 ON cf.client_id = cf3.client_id
 INNER JOIN client_form_4 cf4 ON cf.client_id = cf4.client_id
 INNER JOIN client_form_5 cf5 ON cf.client_id = cf5.client_id
 INNER JOIN client_form_6 cf6 ON cf.client_id = cf6.client_id
 INNER JOIN client_form_7 cf7 ON cf.client_id = cf7.client_id
");
```

Comment: How do you need to deal with this? Should all duplicate rows in every table be first collapsed to a single row? GROUP BY would collapse rows, before joining.

Comment: If, I'm guessing, all the data is of the same structure, why is it split across several tables?

Comment: ^ this. Please don't. Have one master table and if you need to identify the clients somehow use a column in the table to do the identification, don't use multiple tables to contain the same kind of data.

Comment: Jonast92 it's not same kind of data every table contain different content I don't want to create one large tabel with 40 columns so what can I do to unite all the data from the 7 tabels